# How to pass component function return value to service in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api

In the following html page i am displaying job details in bootstrap panel from json array using ngFor loop.Each panel displays particular job detail with jobid. Here i have click event.This click event triggers the onclick method in the TS file.

### jobseeker.component.html

```
<div *ngFor='let joblist of joblists?.all_search_view' >
    <a style="text-decoration:none" (click)="onclick(joblist.job_id)" routerLink="/each-job-detail"
    routerLinkActive="router-link-active">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body bg-color" style="margin-left: 5px">
        <h3 style="color: #00a4e0;margin-top: 10px;"> </h3>
        <p style="font-size: 18px">{{joblist.role}}
          <span style="float:right;margin-right: 5px">{{joblist.job_add_date}}</span> </p>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="column">Job Location: {{joblist.location}}</div>
          <div class="column">Job Id: {{joblist.job_id}}</div>
          <div class="column">Salary: {{joblist.salary}}</div>
        </div>
  </div>
  </div>
   </a>
  </div>
```

### jobseeker.component.ts

When i click on the panel this onclick method returns jobid in my console.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { JoblistService } from 'src/app/service/joblist/joblist.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-jobseeker',
  templateUrl: './jobseeker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./jobseeker.component.css']
})
export class JobseekerComponent implements OnInit {

  public joblists: any = {};
  constructor(private _joblistsService: JoblistService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._joblistsService. getjoblists()
    .subscribe(data => this.joblists = data);
  }
  onclick(jobid: BigInteger) {
  console.log(jobid);
}
}
```

I want to pass this jobid into one of my following service(ex:id=jobid).Because this jobid will be used in my service url as(this.id).How can i do it.

### jobdetails.service.ts

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';
import { Jobdetail } from './jobdetail';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'

})
export class JobdetailService {

  id = jobid;

   private _url: any = 'http://13.126.181.94:8087/job_detail_description.php?job_id='+ this.id + '&action=filter';
   constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }
    getjobdetails(): Observable<Jobdetail[]> {
    return this.http.get<Jobdetail[]>(this._url);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass the job Id to `getjobdetails();` method, then you can pass it as an argument to the function like

job-seeker.component

```
constructor(private _joblistsService: JoblistService, 
            private _jobDetailService : JobdetailService) { }

onclick(jobid: BigInteger) {
  console.log(jobid);
  this._jobDetailService .getjobdetails(jobid).subscribe().
}
```

Also modify your `JobdetailService` service accordingly

```
getjobdetails(id): Observable<Jobdetail[]> {
    return this.http.get<Jobdetail[]>(this._url + '/' + id);
}
```

Comment: i want to pass jobid to jobdetail.service.ts which is separate service not related to this (jobseeker) component. jobseeker component is related with joblist.service.ts. The method getjobdetails() is in jobdetail.service.ts file not in joblist.service.ts

Comment: Then you can directly inject `JobdetailService` in your component `jobseeker`and call `this._jobDetailService.getjobdetails(jobid)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use observable and behavior subject for id field in service. Like this:

service file:

```
_id: BehaviorSubject<Number> = new BehaviorSubject(Number);

id: Observable<Number> = this._id.asObservable();

private _url: any = 'http://13.126.181.94:8087/job_detail_description.php?job_id='+ this._id.getValue() + '&action=filter';
```

change the value of id from your component by calling next() function like this:

```
onclick(jobid: BigInteger) {
  this._joblistsService._id.next(jobid);
}
```

For more information regarding this approach refer the following:

https://blog.angular-university.io/how-to-build-angular2-apps-using-rxjs-observable-data-services-pitfalls-to-avoid/

Comment: in the first line of your answer (_id) throws error. Type 'BehaviorSubject<NumberConstructor>' is not assignable to type 'BehaviorSubject<Number>'. and  Type 'NumberConstructor' is missing the following properties from type 'Number': toFixed, toExponential, toPrecision ts(2322).

Comment: its just issue with datatype. Try using 'number' instead.